# Dropdown with inbuilt filter does not set the v-model value in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

[image]

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
        <label>Select Store</label>
        <select @change="store_staff()"   v-model="form.store_id" class="form-control select2-single" data-width="100%">
            <option label="&nbsp;">Store</option>
            <option  v-for="(name,id) in store_data" :value="id">{{name}}</option>                      
       </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

This above is html with binding model in dropdown but the value in v-model is not set.

Comment: Add `value` attribute to your `<option>`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this please,

```
<select  @change="store_staff()"  v-model="store_id" >
            <option>Store</option>
            <option  v-for="(key,i) in store_data" :value="key">{{i}}</option>                      
       </select>
<span>Selected: {{ store_id }}</span>
```

Here is the codepen

https://codepen.io/sandstedt/pen/GRZeywP

Comment: data is in Single Dimension  like: { "2": "name113", "6": "my storeee", "9": "2 sept test11", "12": "3 september", "14": "new store 3 sept1" }